# SQL condition, Admin user vs non admin user

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I simplified the query a lot, it is much bigger, but only this one WHERE is the issue.

An Admin user should see all records, non admin user should not.

I have a variable `@IsAdmin` for the current logged in user

Then I have to get the list.

```
 if @isadmin = 0
 begin
  /* non admin user */
  select *
  from atable a
  inner join user u where a.user=b.user and b.IsAdmin <> 1
 end
 else
 begin
  /* admin user */
  select *
  from atable a
  inner join user u where a.user=b.user
 end
```

Is there a nicer way to do this, so I don't have the query there twice?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `OR` should do the trick:

```
select *
from atable a
inner join user u 
    on a.user = u.user 
where @isadmin = 1 or b.IsAdmin <> 1
```

Comment: for 1, this only returns admin data, should return all. For 0 returns all data, it should return just non admin data

Answer (score 1):

How about `or`?

```
select *
from atable a join
     user u 
     on a.user = u.user or @IsAdmin = 1;
```

I don't understand what the condition `IsAdmin <> 1` is supposed to be doing.  It seems unnecessary.

That said, I suspect you need to take the current user into account.  So I'm guessing something more like:

```
select a.*
from atable a
where a.user = @current_user or @isAdmin = 1;
```